# Connect to Exchange server using powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried running the following script to connect to an exchange server but I get the below error. Is anything wrong with the script? Are there any changes to be done from the server end?

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$LiveCred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://mail.company.tld/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Error:

```
New-PSSession : [mail.deloitte.ca] Connecting to remote server mail.deloitte.ca failed with the following error message : The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP 
server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually returned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management protocol. 
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:4 char:12
+ $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conne ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : URLNotAvailable,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Comment: You should remove the company name from the Url in your question.

Comment: What Powershell version is running on the server / client?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked PowerShellVirtualDirectory as mentioned in [this document](https://jaapwesselius.com/2015/09/09/the-requested-http-url-was-not-available/)? It mentions exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ConnectionUri is correct, most likely PowerShell remoting is not enabled on the target CAS server. You can enable it by running this on the CAS server directly:

```
Enable-PSRemoting
```

You *may* also need to configure the PowerShell virtual directory with:

```
Set-PowerShellVirtualDirectory "[ServerName]\POWERSHELL (default web site)" -BasicAuthentication $true
```